# Option not to show closed/duplicate questions in search

Tags: support, search

When searching for questions to answer, many of the questions are either closed or duplicates. Is there a way to hide these questions?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

[Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bperl%5D%20is%3Aquestion%20answers%3A0%20closed%3Ano%20duplicate%3Ano%20migrated%3Ano)?

Comment: While this answer can potentially be edited in shape by community to stop being a link-only post there is not much value in doing so as we have enough duplicates showing how to search non-closed questions... James Risner, consider either editing or mod-flagging for deletion (as you can't delete accepted answer).